# ! Missing number, treated as zero error beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, thesis

I'm working on my thesis' presentation with Beamer but I am facing the same problem which I did not know the reason everytime i compile this "! Missing number, treated as zero" everytime shows up in log file, please any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

PS: I edited the post and posted my real code not only a sample.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer} 

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Footer section
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{footlinerule}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!25!bg}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.5ex,dp=0ex,center]{footlinerule}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.6ex,dp=0ex,center]{empty}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in
head/foot}%
  \insertshortauthor\hspace{1em}(\insertshortinstitute)
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,right]{date in head/foot}%

    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}%

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Report title
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\author{Me}
\title{application web pour gestion des filtres}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{logo.png}} 
\institute[ESSECT]{ESSECT} 
\date{18 mai 2015} 
\subtitle{Rapport du projet fin d’étude}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%sommaire automatique
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamerfont{myTOC}{series=\bfseries,size=\Large}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sommaire}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections, pausesubsections]
  \end{frame} 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

\frametitle{Table des matières}
\tableofcontents[pausesections]

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

\frametitle{Cadre du projet et l'étude de l'éxistant}
\section[]{Cadre du projet et l'étude de l'existant}
\subsection{Introduction}
Dans ce niveau on va comprendre le domaine ou le metier de l'entreprise et des personnes qui y travaillent pour mieux satisfaire leurs besoins. Il s'agit aussi de construire
l'organigramme de l'organisation l'étudiée.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsection{Cadre du stage}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Environnement du stage}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Historique}
\subsubsection{Principales missions}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsection{L'organigramme}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsection{Étude de l'éxistant}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Déscription}

\subsubsection{Analyse de l'éxistant}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Problématiques}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Solution envisagée}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsection{Méthodologie de developpement et conception}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Modèle de conception}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Langage UML}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Approche en Cascade}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Conclusion}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\section{Capture des besoins}
\end{frame}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Extra slides that won't effect my page numbering
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\appendix 
\begin{frame}{First Extra slide}
...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\def\newblock{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get a different error because of the missing `\begin{frame}` for the latest `\end{frame}`.

Comment: @MahouachiMayssa Please edit your question to give the mentioned error message. Right now, If you just add `\begin{frame}` for the last `\end{frame}`, it works error-free.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault I forgot \begin{frame} while typing to post the question, I checked my codes again and there is no such a missing \begin{frame}, the error is still there too.

Comment: The sectional commands should be outside the frames.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you  for your reply, could you please specify more which commands aren't outside the frames?

Comment: `section`, `subsection` and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have code in your preamble which sets a frame the moment, you call a section. You should therefore nor put a section inside a frame here. Kind of doubled:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\AtBeginSection[]
{%
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sommaire}
\end{frame} 
}

\begin{document}        
%\begin{frame}
    \section[]{Cadre du projet et l'étude de l'existant}    
%\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Btw.: The code posted here would have been sufficient for your minimal working example. For future question please try to break down the actual error.

Comment: thank you for the reply i guess that's the problem but I can not confirm it since it came out an other one, I'm posting new question when I fix it, I'll get back here and vote.